# Are jQuery UI key is required when i want to use Google Ajax API

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i want to use Google jQuery UI. are i can use them without key.

are i can get the custom css of jQuery UI from CDN if i want.

Comment: You can't get custom CSS's from their CDN, the normal ones are on Google's CDN (and Microfts'): http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/12/jquery-ui-1-8-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need API key just use this for latest version of jQuery:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript"  charset="utf-8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For jQuery UI:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  charset="utf-8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Google’s servers return a 304 “Not Modified” response if the file is requested again. Files are cached for one year.